# Scanner issuses in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class RPS {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int comp=0, user=0;
        char temp = ' ';
        System.out.println("Enter Q to quit.");
        while(user!=4){
            comp = rand.nextInt(3);
            System.out.print("Enter your choice (R, P, S): ");
            temp = scan.nextChar();
            if(temp =='R' || temp =='r')
                user=1;
            if(temp =='P' || temp =='p')
                user=2;
            if(temp =='S' || temp =='s')
                user=3;
            else
                user=4;
            ...
```

I cut off the end of my code after what was important. Im getting an error on the line that says "temp = scan.nextChar();" that says symbol not found. What is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner` does not have `nextChar` method you can use `next` instead to get character as a `String`.

```
String charInput = scan.next();
char character = charInput.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no [`Scanner#nextChar()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) method. Instead you can do `temp = scan.next().charAt(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't find nextChar() in Scanner. Use next() or nextLine()